# При добавление нового элемента в коллекцию, все остальные тоже изменяются

Tags: java

При добавления нового элемента в список, все остальные элементы тоже меняются.
Staic нигде нет, элемент создаю новый, не понимаю в чем проблема.

```
public class BubbleSort {

 class SortState{
    private int[] curArr;
    private int i;
    private int j;

    public SortState(int[] curArr, int i, int j){
        this.curArr = curArr;
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }

    public int[] getArr(){
        return this.curArr;
    }
}
public  ArrayList<SortState> sort(int[] data) {
    int size = data.length;
    ArrayList<SortState> res = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 1; i < size - 1; ++i) {
        for(int j = size - 1; j >= i; --j) {
            if (data[j - 1] > data[j]) {
                int temp = data[j - 1];
                data[j - 1] = data[j];
                data[j] = temp;
            }
            res.add(new SortState(data, i, j));
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то проблема тут в отличии ссылочного типа от примитива.
int - примитив, однако, массив (даже если это массив примитивов) - ссылочный тип. поэтому все операции вы производите с одним массивом, просто передавая ссылку на него из метода в метод. именно поэтому в результате во всех объектах SortState вы видите одинаковый массив : потому что он всего один и все объекты SortState  хранят в себе ссылку на этот единственный объект массива. 
Возможное решение - измените конструктор класса SortState так:

```
public SortState(int[] curArr, int i, int j) {
    this.curArr = new int[curArr.length];
    System.arraycopy(curArr, 0, this.curArr, 0, curArr.length);
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
}
```